# digital envelope routines upsupported. [Error - React]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I downloaded a pre-made react app I want to add features to, ran npm install and upon npm start I receive an error related to a hash of which I do not know how to solve:

```
[noah@Qyain widgets]$ npm start

> widgets@1.0.0 start
> webpack --mode=development --watch


webpack is watching the files…

node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (/home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /home/noah/Documents/JS-ark/aA/widgets/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:51:71
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I tried looking into the web.config file but to no avail. Html where the root is rendered is as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>React Widgets</title>
  <link href="stylesheets/application.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/index.css"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have several widgets in a fronted folder, below is the weather widget:

```
import React from 'react';

const toQueryString = (obj) => {
  const parts = [];
  for (let i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          parts.push(`${encodeURIComponent(i)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[i])}`);
      }
  }
  return parts.join('&');
}

export default class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weather: null
    };
    this.pollWeather = this.pollWeather.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.pollWeather);
  }

  pollWeather(location) {
    let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
    const params = {
      lat: location.coords.latitude,
      lon: location.coords.longitude
    };
    url += toQueryString(params);
    const apiKey = 'f816d7f39052e3a98b21952097a43076';
    // This is our API key; please use your own!
    url += `&APPID=${apiKey}`; // make url to make API calls via .open 
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
      //ready state of DONE means this is complete
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200 && xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        const data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        this.setState({weather: data});
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

  render() {
    let content = <div> </div>; // this content is gonna be populated. 

    if (this.state.weather) {
      const weather = this.state.weather;
      const temp = (weather.main.temp - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32;
      content = <div>
                  <p>{weather.name}</p>
                  <p>{weather.rain} </p>
                  <p>{weather.humidity}</p>
                  <p>{temp.toFixed(1)} degrees</p>
                </div>;
    } else {
      content = <div className='loading'>loading weather...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Weather</h1>
        <div className='weather'>
          {content}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Along with a package-json:

```
{
  "name": "widgets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --mode=development --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

auto.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

export default class AutoComplete extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputVal: ''
    };
    this.selectName = this.selectName.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    this.setState({inputVal: event.currentTarget.value});
  }

  matches() {
    const matches = [];
    if (this.state.inputVal.length === 0) {
      return this.props.names;
    }

    this.props.names.forEach(name => {
      const sub = name.slice(0, this.state.inputVal.length);
      if (sub.toLowerCase() === this.state.inputVal.toLowerCase()) {
        matches.push(name);
      }
    });

    if (matches.length === 0) {
      matches.push('No matches');
    }

    return matches;
  }

  selectName(event) {
    const name = event.currentTarget.innerText;
    this.setState({inputVal: name});
  }

  render() {
    const results = this.matches().map((result, i) => {
      return (
        <li key={i} onClick={this.selectName}>{result}</li>
      );
    });
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Autocomplete</h1>
        <div className='auto'>
          <input
            onChange={this.handleInput}
            value={this.state.inputVal}
            placeholder='Search...'/>
          <ul>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName='auto'
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
              {results}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Of which all tie together to widgets.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import AutoComplete from './auto';
import Clock from './clock';
import Weather from './weather';
import Tabs from './tabs';

const names = [
  'Abba',
  'Barney',
  'Barbara',
  'Jeff',
  'Jenny',
  'Sarah',
  'Sally',
  'Xander'
];

const panes = [
  {title: 'one', content: 'I am the first'},
  {title: 'two', content: 'Second pane here'},
  {title: 'three', content: 'Third pane here'}
];

function Root() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Clock />
      <Weather />
      <div className='interactive'>
        <Tabs panes={panes} />
        <AutoComplete names={names} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('main'));
});
```

I keep running this problem and I think it has something to do with webpack but I am unsure, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your package.json: change this line

> "start": "react-scripts start"

to

> "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"

Comment: Okay, I receive this error: "[noah@Qyain myapp]$ npm start

> myapp@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start

/usr/bin/node: bad option: --openssl-legacy-provider"
Why am I doing this exactly? Is it because a lot of this code is deprecated?

Comment: the issue is actually with nodejs version 17+, might help if you're using a stable version

Comment: Yes, okay I understand but why is it happening regardless of the fact and how can we fix it since this question is already up and people put effort into answering it?

Comment: This is working fine after I made this edit .. but it would be better having an explanation why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

I am running into this issue with `v18.7.0` but I am using nx and storybook.

I worked around the issue by specifying node options

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' nx storybook core 
# NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' my_custom_node_script
```